# Angular / JS generate random Uniq Serial ID

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, random, uuid

I'm creating a function that generate a random Uniq Serial id by replacing a string with this format ; **xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx** , the goal is to get a serial like that : ***ABCD-1234-EFGH-5678*** ,the first and third parts are a letters and the second and last parts are numbers, this is my code :

```
public generateUniqSerial() {
   return 'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx'.replace(/[x]/g, function (c) {
     let r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)
     return v.toString(16)
   })
 }
```

it give a result like that : **"7f8f-0d9a-fd5-450f"**
, how to edit this function to get a result with this format : ABCD-1234-EFGH-6789 ?

Comment: Why do you want to make less unique Ids?

Comment: why not just use a package like uuid btw?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Comment: Try this: `function generateUniqSerial() {
  return 'xxxx-aaaa-xxxx-aaaa'.replace(/[xa]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
      v = (c == 'x' || c == 'a') ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return (c == 'x') ? String.fromCharCode((+v || 10) + 0x40) : v.toString(8).charAt(0);
  })
}

console.log(generateUniqSerial());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to generate a random Uniq Serial id with a format like `ABCD-1234-EFGH-5678`:

```js
function rnd(t) {
  let str = '';
  const min = t === 'a' ? 10 : 0;
  const max = t === 'n' ? 10 : 62;
  for (let i = 0; i++ < 4;) {
    let r = Math.random() * (max - min) + min << 0;
    str += String.fromCharCode(r += r > 9 ? r < 36 ? 55 : 61 : 48);
  }
  return str;
}

function generateUniqSerial() {
  return `${rnd('a')}-${rnd('n')}-${rnd('a')}-${rnd('n')}`
}

console.log(generateUniqSerial())
console.log(generateUniqSerial())
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm asked to do things like this I like to start with a "string of letters" and a "string of digits."  My logic then simply consists of choosing a random index into the appropriate source string to get each character that I need.  I like to do it this way because to me it's "extremely obvious" what I am doing and equally easy to desk-check that it will work.